# jQuery to Pass a Static Value if search is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing the search string using `$('input[type="text"]').val()`

Now the requirement is:
if it is a blank search, then I want to pass *Blank Search* as the value instead of `$('input[type="text"]').val()`

AND

if it not blank and having a value, I want to pass the same value using `$('input[type="text"]').val()`.

What I have tried:

```
$(document).on('click','.fa.fa-search', function()
{
    ga('create', {{ GA Property }}, 'auto'); 
    ga('send', 'event', 'Search', 
    function blank () 
    { 
      alert('hi');
        var srchStr = $('input[type="text"]').val(); 
        if(srchStr == '') { srchStr = "Blank Search"; }
    }, 
    window.location.href); 
});
```

How to do it?

Comment: you can use ternary `($('input[type="text"]').val().trim().length > 0) ? $('input[type="text"]').val() : "Blank Search"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var srchStr = $('input[type="text"]').val();
if(srchStr == '')
{
    srchStr = "Blank Search";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example with avoiding extra spaces.

```
var v = $('input[type="text"]').val().replace(/\s+/,"");
v = v === "" ? "Blank Search" : $('input[type="text"]').val();
```

Comment: <script>
$(document).on('click','.fa.fa-search', function(){
ga('create', {{GA Property}}, 'auto');
ga('send', 'event', 'Search',
   function blank ()
   {
   var srchStr = $('input[type="text"]').val();
if(srchStr == '')
{
    srchStr = "Blank Search";
}}, window.location.href);
}) 
</script>


This is my original code which I have..

If the search is blank then I want the value as "Blank Search" and if it not blank then I want the search value/string.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/8t0xf5dz/1/)

html:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" val="test">
```

jquery :

```
$('input[type="button"]').on("click", function() {
  var val = $('input[type="text"]').val().trim().length > 0 ? $('input[type="text"]').val() : "Your Default value"
  alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
if($('input[type="text"]').val() == '')
{
    $('input[type="text"]').val("Blank Search");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    var input =  $('input[type="text"]');
    var srchStr = input.val();

```
if(srchStr != '' && srchStr.trim().length > 0){
  input.val(srchStr);
}else{
  input.val("Blank Search");
}
```